# DROP and CREATE the same trigger in the same sintaxis

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, heidisql

Dummy question: Have the next code in MySQL, but when run it in HeidiSQL, show a sintaxis error near '// CREATE TRIGGER'. I'm not sure if that happen because the trigger doesn't exists. This is the code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS oportunidades_movimiento_entregado //
CREATE TRIGGER oportunidades_movimiento_entregado;
AFTER INSERT ON historial_entregado
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE oportunidades
SET oportunidades.fechaModificado = NEW.fecha_creacion
WHERE NEW.oportunidad_id = oportunidades.id;
END//
```

**UPDATE**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS oportunidades_movimiento_entregado $$
CREATE TRIGGER oportunidades_movimiento_entregado
AFTER INSERT ON historial_entregado
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE oportunidades
SET oportunidades.fechaModificado = NEW.fecha_creacion
WHERE NEW.oportunidad_id = oportunidades.id;
END; $$
DELIMITER //
```

This works, but now my doubt is... All the code (the DROP and the CREATE) will run everytime, or just the CREATE? I need this because I'm working with 2 tables, in one of them I insert/update the data, after with a trigger insert some of the columns in another table to keep a historial, but when I make a INSERT or UPDATE query in the first table, MySQL display the error #1442

> Can't update table `oportunidades` in stored/function trigger because it's already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, set the delimiter first and reset it after the CREATE TRIGGER statement.
Remove the semicolon at the end of the CREATE TRIGGER line.

This should work:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS oportunidades_movimiento_entregado //

CREATE TRIGGER oportunidades_movimiento_entregado    -- no trailing semicolon here
    AFTER INSERT ON historial_entregado
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE oportunidades
        SET oportunidades.fechaModificado = NEW.fecha_creacion
        WHERE NEW.oportunidad_id = oportunidades.id;
    END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Error in the SQL syntax... to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1 :(